# jQuery/JavaScript adding a number to a value retrieved from.text()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a id on my page that I am trying to retrieve a number from and add a value to. For instance:

```
<td id="qty_295518">1700</td>

 var quantity = 1; 
 var currentQty = +(jQuery.trim($("#qty_295518").text()));
 var newQty = parseInt(currentQty, 10) + quantity;
```

When I try and add the numbers together it come out looking like this:

```
17001 instead of 1701
```

It is just appending the 1 to the end of 1700 instead of adding it to 1700. I have tried to use parseInt, +() but to no avail. Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you parsing it? Just do `Number(currentQty)`

Comment: @BradM he doesn't even have to do that, because of the `+` unary operator on the line before.

Comment: Well, parseInt should return an int and quantity is a number. I can't see how this could happen. What environment are you in?

Comment: You need to post more code; the posted code is not causing your problem.

Comment: Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/nDseG/ Works like a charm...

Comment: I pasted your code into jsFiddle and everything is fine, except that you can't just have a `<td>` hanging just by itself otherwise it's invalid html and the browser removes it completely. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FuVUW/1/

Comment: Yeah its not by itself, i was just demonstrating. It so weird i see it working in your fiddle but my altered code will not produce the same results.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 var quantity = 1; 
 var currentQty = +(jQuery.trim($("#qty_295518").text()));
 var newQty = parseInt(currentQty, 10);
 newQty += quantity;
```

Comment: Why would this make *any* difference?

Comment: Sorry forgot to add at the end: $("#qty_295518").text(newQty); When I plug that into the js fiddle it works for me, anyway.

Comment: The issue was coming from the var quantity, since it was a dynamic var I had to wrap it in parseInt and it then worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I made a few changes from yours but they're not too different. Here's my jsfiddle, maybe it will help? I've put an alert in there to let you know that the correct value is being returned

http://jsfiddle.net/muBJd/1/

I don't know if this is the case in your actual code, but make sure that the td is wrapped in tr and table tags.

#### Html

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="qty_295518">1700</td>
    </tr> 
</table>
```

#### Jquery / Javascript

```
 var quantity = 1; 
 var targetQuantity = $('#qty_295518').text();
 var myInteger = parseInt(targetQuantity, 10);
 var addingQuantities = myInteger + quantity;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are doing something wrong outside from jquery code, because jquery code is working fine as I wrapped the `<td>` inside the `<tr>` of `<table>`. something like this.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="qty_295518">1700</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UZndj/)